# TWRP stuck at splash screen - Nexus 6P Android N

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, nexus-6p, 7.0-nougat

I am following this guide: [[GUIDE] Unlock/Root/Flash for Nexus 6P](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guides-how-to-guides-beginners-t3206928)

The bootloader is already unlocked. Now I'm trying to flash the **TWRP recovery**. (Section 2). As the device runs Android N, I first flashed the modified `boot.img` (like in the guide, also tried it with stock boot.img) and then I flashed the **TWRP recovery** like this:

```
username@my_pc:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./fastboot flash boot '/home/username/Downloads/boot.img' 
target reported max download size of 494927872 bytes
sending 'boot' (12272 KB)...
OKAY [  0.333s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.185s]
finished. total time: 0.518s
username@my_pc:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./fastboot flash recovery '/home/username/Downloads/twrp.img'
target reported max download size of 494927872 bytes
sending 'recovery' (16932 KB)...
OKAY [  0.453s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.251s]
finished. total time: 0.704s
```

Then I rebooted to the **bootloader** again, and then booted to the **recovery mode**, like explained in the guide:

> Use the volume keys to scroll and power key to select the Reboot Bootloader option. Once the phone has booted back into the bootloader you can use the volume keys to scroll and the power key to boot into your newly flashed recovery. It's now safe to disconnect your usb cable.

However, it just hangs at the TWRP splash screen:

[image: Stuck at TWRP splash screen]

The phone still works and can successfully boot to Android N. I know the bootloader is unlocked because of the unlock symbol at boot logo, and I rooted it (same guide) on Android Marshmallow.

About phone (click for larger image):

[image: About phone]

Comment: What is the content of the **.twrps** file, stored in the internal storage, under the **TWRP** folder?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman The file doesn't exist. I left it at the TWRP splash screen for about a minute, and then checked for the file.

Comment: That's a file used by TWRP for remembering its preferences. It usually gets created by the recovery itself. What's your TWRP version?

Comment: `twrp-3.0.2-0-angler.img`. I downloaded it here: https://dl.twrp.me/angler/ @DeathMaskSalesman

Comment: See if you can find a **.twrps** somewhere, and place it manually in the abovementioned folder. This may or may not fix the issue, but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman What do you mean by finding a **.twrps** file?

Comment: Fire up Google, and search for such file. See if you can find one, download it and place it in the **TWRP** folder.

Comment: I had to format user data to get twrp to work ... but there is a guide on how to do it without losing your data http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6p/general/guide-android-nougat-developer-preview-t3410906

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of TWRP for your device *(3.6.0_9-0)*. Around ***4 thousand*** changes have been made since 3.0.2-0 *(around 800 files)*.

*Source: [GitHub Comparison](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_bootable_recovery/compare/android-7.0...android-9.0)*

Comment: While recommending to use the latest version is generally not a bad idea, it might be more reasonable to mention the minimum specific version that works, because at the time the question was posted in 2016, this version hasn't existed yet.

Comment: Fair enough. I just checked that. But they still have no logs from recovery.